# Functional operations (such as filtering) on promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am performing several queries simultaneously and creating an array of promises from them. I want the resulting array to only have certain properties returned from the query, and I want to filter others (but these operations could really be anything). Currently, I have:

```
Promise.all(Ids.map(Id => query(Id)
  .then(result => result.Item)
)).then(results => results.filter(Boolean));
```

The internal `result.Item` is still done in parallel, so I think this is okay, but I don't like this for two reasons:

1. I have an internal / nested promise chain I would like to flatten
2. The outer filtering has to wait for all promises to complete (expected) and then iterate over the entire result (bad). It would be preferable not to add empty items in the first place.

Is there a preferred way to perform functional operations on a collection of promises?

Comment: There is zilch wrong with #1. You're not trying to "flatten" `for` loops either, do you?

Comment: Might want to switch to Rx

Comment: @Bergi the `map` / iterative / loop piece is not what I want to flatten. I think flatten is the wrong word, but my issue with it is the internal promise chain (`.then`)

Comment: @ExplosionPills: The inner chain (in the `map` callback) is just what the loop body would be. There's nothing to flatten here. You can try `async`/`await` or Bluebirds `Promise.coroutine` though if you don't want to chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Reactive Extensions library, which provides a way to integrate different models for asynchronicity into a conceptual "stream" model. E.g. the code you have up there (assuming `Ids` is an array and `query` returns a promise) would turn into this:

```
Observable.from(Ids)
    .flatMap(id => query(id))
    .map(result => result.Item)
    .filter(item => item.filterByThis) // Not sure what Boolean is supposed to be in your code
    .toArray();
```

Assuming `Ids` is an `number[]`, we start out by producing an `Observable<number>`, then pass it through various familiar looking operators to transform and filter the stream, then finally use `toArray` get an observable that emits a single array of whatever type `result.Item` is supposed to be.

You can think of Observables as a generalization of the concept of promises to asynchronous operations that return any number of values, rather than just one. This is a powerful paradigm, and the Rx library is pretty popular in many languages. You can read more about it [here](http://reactivex.io/) or get started with [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) npm package.

Comment: By the way, `Boolean` is just the boolean constructor in JavaScript, so `.filter(Boolean)` is just a way of writing `.filter(item => Boolean(item))` or `.filter(item => !!item)`

Comment: How do you generate `Observable` in your example? `const Observable = require("rxjs").Observable`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Depends which one you're using. If you're using RxJS 5, you'd do `const Observable = require('rxjs/Rx').Observable;`. I think it's a bit different for RxJS 4. Best place to check is the github READMEs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs.

Comment: There's also a gitter chatroom here: https://gitter.im/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS where there's some really helpful folks if you're having trouble with liftoff.